# Regular expression does not match, no idea why

Tags: regex, sh

I moved my server to a new one (cheaper). Both have the same Linux (CentOS) in different versions (5.0 and 6.5). I have a shell script that filters a line out of a log:

```
if [ -f $URLFILE ]
then
  echo "File found, getting userinfo..."
  while read line;
    do
    if [[ $line =~ ".Userlist: .*" ]]
    then
      echo "Found user information."
      echo $line > /home/....net.txt;
...
```

So, if the red line matches the regex, it should be echoed into the file. This works fine on the old system but the regex does not match on the new system (without any other changes). The regex is correct as far as a regex tester on the Internet tells me.

Comment: What version of `bash` (which I assume is the shell you are using) is on each machine?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

1. `sh` doesn't support regex matching using `=~` like `bash`
2. Regex should NOT be quoted and your variable should preferably be quoted.

You can use this in BASH:

```
if [[ "$line" =~ Userlist:[[:blank:]] ]]
```

OR just avoid using regex altogether and use `glob matching`:

```
if [[ "$line" == *"Userlist: "* ]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I still do not understand why it worked on the old server for years, but I'll probably never know...

Comment: Actually I know why it would have worked on old system. It is because older BASH version e.g. 3.1 used to work with quoted regex string. That's why newer BASH versions have a special variable called `compat31` to make it behave like older one.